# Change column Timezone to Time

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, alter-table

By mistake, a table was set up having a column type Timestamp without time zone, where type Time will be needed.
I tried

```
ALTER TABLE "Scheme"."Table" ALTER COLUMN "Length" TYPE _time USING "Length"::_time;
```

and got an ERROR: cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to time without time zone

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_time` isn't a [valid Postgres data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). You need to use `time`

```
ALTER TABLE "Scheme"."Table" 
  ALTER COLUMN "Length" TYPE time USING "Length"::time;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=20eea6f3c662f8ec25891657040ed3be)

Comment: Tried this, the command is accepted without error. But after that, the column is still Timestamp?

Comment: No it's not. Maybe you forgot to `commit` that?

Comment: OK, I've got it! It was committed but not yet updated in the front-end. Sorry for my confusion.